# How do I use regex to sort elements of a list?

Tags: ruby, regex, sorting

```
list = [
  'Urząd Skarbowy 59-700 Bolesławiec ul. Garncarska 10',
  'Urząd Skarbowy 57-500 Bystrzyca Kłodzka ul. Adama Mickiewicza 5',
  'Urząd Skarbowy 58-200 Dzierżoniów ul. Pocztowa 14',
  'Urząd Skarbowy 67-200 Głogów ul. Adama Mickiewicza 53'
]
```

I would like to sort this list by city - the string, which appears to be between postal index (`dd-ddd`) and word `ul`. In this case the cities are:

```
['Bolesławiec', 'Bystrzyca Kłodzka', 'Dzierżoniów', 'Głogów']
```

What is the nice way to achieve it?

Comment: Why does this have to be efficient, are you going to sort the list over and over again? :-)

Comment: @Stefan, you always there to spot tiny things :) Updated question

Comment: What are the rules for sorting, e.g. how are accented characters supposed to be sorted?

Comment: I think it would be enough to go with default string sorting. I do not understand, why mudasobwa's solution fails with whole collection

Comment: And sort Łask after Złotów, are you sure? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
▶ list.sort_by { |s| s[/(?<=\d\d-\d\d\d\s).*?(?=ul.)/] }
#⇒ [
#  [0] "Urząd Skarbowy 59-700 Bolesławiec ul. Garncarska 10",
#  [1] "Urząd Skarbowy 57-500 Bystrzyca Kłodzka ul. Adama Mickiewicza 5",
#  [2] "Urząd Skarbowy 58-200 Dzierżoniów ul. Pocztowa 14",
#  [3] "Urząd Skarbowy 67-200 Głogów ul. Adama Mickiewicza 53"
# ]
```

Please note, that the regexp above assumes that you have `ul.` as street name terminator. Probably in most cases it’s safe to go with the first word in the street name (or to invent more sophisticated terminator.)

```
▶ list.sort_by { |s| s[/(?<=\d{2}-\d{3}\s)\w+/] }
```

*UPD* The combine:

```
▶ list.sort_by do |s| 
▷   s[/(?<=\d\d-\d\d\d\s).*?(?=ul.)/] || \ # try to catch `ul.`
▷   s[/(?<=\d{2}-\d{3}\s)\p{Alpha}+/] || \ # no worries, use first word
▷   '' # OK, failed to catch anything
▷ end
```

Please note `\p{Alpha}` matcher, `\w` won’t work here due to diacritics.

*NB* the more I think about, the more I am convinced that if no `ul.` was catched, it should be sorted by match till the end of string:

```
▶ list.sort_by do |s| 
▷   (s[/(?<=\d\d-\d\d\d\s).*?(?=ul.)/] || s[/(?<=\d{2}-\d{3}\s).+?$/]).strip
▷ end
```

Comment: Sorry for changing the requirement on the fly, but I've noticed that few entries do not have `ul` part. Can the regex be conditional? Like leave it as it is if `ul` is there, otherwise take only first word after `dd-ddd`? Wow, you actually assumed it before I noticed it as a problem :)

Comment: `.*?` is generally a bad idea. Use `\w+` instead, I think it is enough (and remove the lookahead `(?=ul.)` where `.` matches any character but a newline).

Comment: Applying any of two solutions to the whole collection I get `ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with String failed`

Comment: The latter error means that regexp did not catch anything. I will update an answer in a matter of minutes.

Comment: `list.sort_by { |s| s[/\d{2}-\d{3}\s+(.*)/, 1] }` could work as well, i.e. just sort by everything after `dd-ddd`